# Show bootstrap modal on the center of a scrolled down page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using [ace admin template](http://ace.jeka.by/) to develop a website, but I have problem placing bootstrap modal on the center of iframe page when I scrolled it down, like this.

[image]

```
$('#modalId').modal({
    show:true,
    backdrop:'static'
})
```

how to make the modal pop up on the center of current view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
    this.getTopWindow(window).ui_confirm(content);

    function ui_confirm(msg, confirm, cancel){
        bootbox.dialog({
            message: "<h5>"+msg+"<h5>",
            animate: false,
            closeButton: false,
            size: "small",
            buttons: {
                main: {
                    label: "取消",
                    className: "btn-inverse btn-sm",
                    callback: function() {
                        if (typeof cancel !== "undefined" && Object.prototype.toString.call(cancel) === "[object Function]") {
                            cancel();
                        }
                    }
                },
                danger: {
                    label: "确定",
                    className: "btn-primary btn-sm",
                    callback: function() {
                        if (typeof confirm !== "undefined" && Object.prototype.toString.call(confirm) === "[object Function]") {
                            confirm();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var scrollTop = window.gui.getTopWindow(window).scrollY;
if(scrollTop > 200){
    $('#modalId').find('.modal-content').css('top',(scrollTop-50)+'px');
}
$('#modalId').modal({
    show:true,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#modalId').modal({
    show:true,
}).css({
    'margin-top': function (){
        return window.gui.getTopWindow(window).scrollY;
    }
});
```